# why wouldnt Apollo client re-render UI after successful cache register?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Just like the screenshot below, I am trying to add a task to my db and render it out on the client side as it updates. It does successfully readQuery and normalize the cache with my db, and adds to cache as below screenshot. The problem is the screen doesn't render again even after my code executes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It does register new task correctly to the cache

Below is my code for this task.

// Apollo Client

```
await createBoard({  
    variables: { title, projectId },  
    refetchQueries: \[  
    {  
    query: GetBoardsDocument,  
    variables: { projectId },  
    },  
    \],  
    update: (cache, { data }) => {  
    const newBoardRes = data?.createBoard.boards;  
    const newBoard = newBoardRes && newBoardRes\[newBoardRes.length - 2\];  
    const existingBoards = cache.readQuery({  
    query: GetBoardsDocument,  
    variables: { projectId },  
    });  
    // console.log("newBoard", newBoard);  
    if (!existingBoards) return;  
    console.log("existingBoards", existingBoards);  
    console.log("newBoardRes", newBoardRes);  
    // cache.evict({ fieldName: "boards:{}" });  
    if (!newBoardRes) return;        cache.writeQuery({  
    query: GetBoardsDocument,  
    variables: { projectId },  
    data: {  
    getBoards: {  
    boards: \[...existingBoards.getBoards.boards, ...newBoardRes\],  
    // boards: \[...newBoardRes\],  
    },  
    },  
    });  
    // console.log("handleCreateBoard", writeRes);  
    if (refetch) refetch();  
    },  
    });  
};
```

I am confused as to why its not updating UI. From what I understand, apollo client updates its cache hence prop data changes, hence should react component rerender.

Am I missing something here?
Please advise.

Comment: "add task" vs "createBoard" ... refetched query request response? ... how rendered? component(+queries) structure?